# HTML web download link for text file

Tags: html, download, skype

I'm using HTML web and i want, that users could download a file like .vbs (skype bot) and then i use code like this:

```
<a href='skypebot.vbs' target='_blank'>download</a>
```

I get just only that file text. How can i make it download link not uploading it to other site like zippyshare?

Comment: Which server technologie are you using?

Answer (score 2):

> How can i make it download link not uploading it to other site like
>   zippyshare?

You can use a `data` link. Put the contents of your file (encoded with `encodeURI()` ) in the link itself:

```
<a href='data:application/octet-stream,encodeURI(hereContentsGoes)' target='_blank'>download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably being recognized as a vbs type by your browser, and trying to display it.

Easiest solution is to zip or tar the file and have that be the downloadable file.

`<a href='skypebot.zip' target='_blank'>download</a>`

Comment: And there is no any other way? :(

Comment: @LukasJankauskas You can possibly add the type on your server to force it to download. If you're using Apache, you can add this to your .htaccess file: `AddType application/octet-stream .vbs`